# (Azure SDK java) How to Enable/Disable each Functions using Java program

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-java-tools

I am using AzureResourceManager(java).

I am able to start/stop Functions by following.

```
FunctionApp app = azureResourceManager.functionApps().getById(id);
app.start();

FunctionApp app = azureResourceManager.functionApps().getById(id);
app.stop();
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.resourcemanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I know we can enable/disable them from Azure portal.
see [Azure Portal Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BomB.png).
I would like to manage it for each function of Functions using java program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is not documented. So if you really need to do this in Java (likely same for SDK of another language), you had to call it directly.

```java
var response = azure.functionApps().manager().httpPipeline().send(
        new HttpRequest(HttpMethod.PUT, "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<site>/functions/<function>/properties/state?api-version=2021-02-01")
            .setHeader("content-type", "application/json")
            .setBody("{\"properties\":\"disabled\"}"))
    .block();
```

`<subscription_id>` can be get via `azure.subscriptionId()` (anyway user provided this when initializing the `azure` object).

As this is undocumented API (Portal calls this API, if you check the browser dev tool), it could be unstable. I couldn't find a documented equivalent.

PS, you might want to upgrade the SDK version to 2.10.0 (2.1.0 is pretty early version and contains some known minor bugs)