# disable Azure function from java SDK

Tags: java, azure-functions, serverless

Im trying to disable an Azure serverless function by using the java client for Azure.
the request seems to return without any errors, but the change is not actually applied.
also, a link for decent documentation for the serverless java client (AzureResourceManager) with examples will be nice.

```
FunctionApp functionApp = azureResourceManager.functionApps().getById(functionId);
FunctionEnvelope f11 = functionApp.listFunctions().stream().findFirst().get();
f11.innerModel().withIsDisabled(true);
functionApp.update().apply();
```

Comment: tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70140354/3224238

Answer (score 0):

found the following solution.
the function enable/disable property is actually an app setting field of the function app. we need to add this configuration to the function app:

```
    functionApp.update().withAppSetting("AzureWebJobs.<function_name>.Disabled", "1").apply();
```